# How to check hover state in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

```
$('#shfaq_foto_prof').hover(
  function() {
      if ($('#shfaq_foto_prof').is(':hover'))  {
  $('#show_upload').fadeIn( 500 );
      } else {
          $('#show_upload').fadeOut( 500 );
          }
});
```

How to check hover state in jQuery and show the div '#show_upload' only when  div "#shfaq_foto_prof" is hovered and hide when is not hover.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#shfaq_foto_prof').hover(

  function() {

     $('#show_upload').fadeIn(500);

  }, function(){

     $('#show_upload').fadeOut(500);

});
```

Docs: http://api.jquery.com/hover/

As written in the specs, `.hover()` supports 2 handlers (`inHandler`, `outHandler`).

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#shfaq_foto_prof').hover(function() {
    $('#show_upload').fadeToggle(500);
}
```